# Php Error on Displaying Third row

Tags: php

```
<option value='$row2['cID']'>".$row2['prefix']."
```

Throws an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in
```

This code works fine:

```
<option>".$row2['prefix']." "."</option><br />
```

How can I add the cID in?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your quoting

```
"<option value='" . $row2['cID'] . "'>".$row2['prefix']."
```

Or better: enclose the whole thing in double-quotes and enclose the array elements in `{}`

```
"<option value='{$row2['cID']}'>{$row2['prefix']}</option>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
$foo = "<option value='".$row2['cID']."'>".$row2['prefix']."";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the single quotes for the "value"

use:

```
"<option value='" . $row2['cID'] . "'>" . $row2['prefix'] . "</option>"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$cID = $row2['cID'];
$prefix = $row2['prefix'];

echo <<< EOF
<option value="$cID">$prefix</option><br />
EOF;
```